# Redirect directory path of misbehaving software

Tags: compatibility

How one can redirect the path a software read/write its per user configuration to outside of user's home root (to ~/config instead) without root, doing crazy mount point or symlinking?

The software doesn't use $XDG_* or $HOME to get the path.

Comment: If it doesn't use `HOME` to find the current user's home directory, what _does_ it use?  And why are symbolic links forbidden?

Comment: I want these files out of sight, a symlink will just nag me that i'm still forced to have that junkyard in my home's root. Software may use getpwuid to get the home path.

Comment: That's the UNIX way these days, your `$HOME` is a junkyard of config files, most of them for utilities you only use about once a year.  Nothing you can do about it.